# discord.js bot hosted on replit not turning on anymore

Tags: node.js, discord.js, localhost, replit

I had my bot hosted for a while on replit.com its been days but suddenly it stopped responding I stopped it and ran again it stopped working, It has been hosted 24/7 for days no error I don't know what to do.

Comment: Replit hosts all bots on shared servers, if your bot is on a server that a poorly coded bot or a malicious bot is hosted on, Discord API has probably rate limited that IP address, This is why it is better to host it on your own server not a shared

Comment: SO isn't Replit customer support, go talk to them. They'll probably make you get their hacker plan thing.

Answer (score 0):

Repl.it uses shared servers therefore at times Discord Rate Limits ip addresses. here is the fix, open your shell in replit and type `kill 1` and press `enter`. after that your replit will refresh and will start working fine as usual.